# GWT RequestFactory non-trivial examples

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Can someone point me the source code of a non-trivial GWT application which uses RequestFactory? I cannot seem to find good tutorials/documentation/books on the subject. All of the official examples are too trivial to apply to real-world situations.

Comment: I think you'll be hard pressed getting a good answer as there is not enough detail in your question. I think it's best to come up with a good example with enough complexity (if you're just evaluating the use of RequestFactory for a larger project) and see if you encounter any real issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following links:

http://javaasylum.blogspot.gr/2010/11/gwt-21-request-factory.html

[http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FDemoRequestFactory](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/DemoRequestFactory%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

There is also a demo implementing the latter example [here](http://demogwtrequestfactory.appspot.com/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know about examples like that, but unfortunately they are too trivial to be of practical use. I know how to set up something simple like described there. What I need are some guidelines and best practices to use in more complex application containing multiple connected types of entities etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only non-trivial example i have come across is http://greatlogic.com/?p=33 . The rest are just a bit of hello world examples.

There are plenty of Google Group Discussions or StackOverflow question answered by T Broyer for reading. My thumb rule is it takes nearly a month of reading, trial and error coding before getting hang of request factory concepts, editors and the various exception handling before hitting performance issues :) like [GWT Requestfactory performance suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977922/gwt-requestfactory-performance-suggestions/13009238#13009238).