# transfer and cache versioned object file

Tags: java, xml, spring, gwt, requestfactory

### Problem definition:

The project setup uses `GWT` on the client side and `Spring` on the server side
There is an object tree of 100 objects. The object describes a complex config file that is **linked to one user**. This object has to be persisted on the server side and can be requested by the client. Both client and server can access all methods and fields in the Object. Once requested by the client, this object tree is cached. The object can be modified by the client and server. If the file is modified by the server, the client downloads the new version. It should be **easy to add extra functionality** to the config object i.e. increasing the version number and adding objects to the tree. The config file is a project file that saves all changes the user did to make the project as it is. The config file is altered regularly (every 3 seconds) by the user. Compare it to for example a Gimp project / PowerPoint file.

### Current architecture:

The server stores the config file in an `XML` format. When the config is requested, this is converted to a Java object that is send from server to client using the `RequestFactory` (`GWT`). The client can modify that object and changes are send to the server. When the client is done, the server saves the new object by replacing the old `XML` file. The client also caches this Java object using the `HML5Storage` (`GWT`). The 5MB limit is not a problem. When a new version of the object is created at the server, e.g. a new object type is added to the tree, the client downloads the new object tree and discards the old one.

### Questions:

- *Is this a good way to approach the problem?*

Maybe I should send the `XML` file directly from the server to the client on the initialisation. Modify this file by the Client and send it back to the server when he is done. The client could store the `XML` file as is in the `HML5Storage`. Maybe there are some odd choices someone can point out.

- *Is there a better format to store this data server side instead of `XML`?*

I chose `XML` because it has good libraries that allow mapping of Java objects to an `XML` file and it allows adding additional functionality easily. Also this data is linked to one user and the data isn't used otherwise. So it seams a bad idea to store this in a relational DB and combine all those objects in a tree (this would take long to assemble).

- *Is the `RequestFactory` also good for the initial download of the
  object tree?*

I've read cases where the `RequestFactory` could take a long time to download a big list of objects. (x 10 in time compared to `RPC`).

If you made it to this point and something isn't clear, I'm happy to add extra details where needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is this a good way to approach the problem?*

Preloading the object on login is a good idea. A better one would be to break the object tree into small parts and load each of them on request, when the user need to edit that specific part of the config. This assumes that instead of providing a single view to edit all the config properties you somewhat "organized" it into many separate forms, which will request part of the config they need only when it is appropriate. It'll need some work but your architectur be more maintainable if that object changes later.

I don't think you are doing it properly since you transform your object tree (I understood it was some big Java object) to XML, instead of sending that object to the client right away. GWT RPC will handle the serialization/deserialization (actually by using JSON instead of XML). Isn't it easier to manipulate a Plain Java object than XML (even with good libraries) ?

*Is there a better format to store this data server side instead of XML?*

I generally use JSON. It also has good libraries. I only use XML when a human need to read the file directly.

But I don't see why you would need either of them. [GWT RPC mechanism](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) will serialize your java object into json automatically. Just provide a "shared" object and (if needed) a converter to convert your object tree to its shared form and back.

*Is the RequestFactory also good for the initial download of the object tree?*

As XML takes more space than JSON and that manipulating XML is slower than manipulating a java object, I would actually advice to use RPC.

Comment: Added two lines to the problem description. I prefer to use the RequestFactory because it will only send changes to the server. The client will make small changes to this file (every 3 seconds) 1) The object config will always be used completely, not just a part of it. I use XML here because you can't save Java Objects as is to disk and later import it when the Java Object's version has changed. 2)I have no experience with JSON. Is it possible to import an old JSON data to a new Java Object? 3) I wouldn't send the XML file with the RequestFactory, but the Java Object that corresponds to it.Thx

Comment: Ok. XML seems to be a good choice as you might need to read the file "by hand". In any case I recommend to make the XML > POJO conversion server-side since you'll have more libraries at your disposal than with GWT. 1) ok 2) do you need to maintain a POJO version up-to-date on the server or to maintain a POJO and an XML version ? I thought the conversion would only occur when reading the XML from your disk or writing the XML back. I don't get it sorry 3) Seems to be the right way to do it. RequestFactory is best for manipulating an entity client-side and keeping it up-to-date on the server.

Comment: For the last part of your question, do you specifically perceive the file download as slow, or did you take some measures of the time needed to retrieve it ?

Comment: I don't have to read the XML by hand, I just happen to have found JAXB which allows some versioning. http://goo.gl/14Ta2o 1) :) 2) The POJO on the server side exists to be able to send it to the client and not having to read/write the XML all the time. Once the client logs off, the POJO is saved as XML and the POJO is destroyed on the server and cached on the client side. 3) The project is in the design phase without any implementation so far. I'm referring to other users e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363495/gwt-requestfactory-performance Thx.

Comment: For versioning using JSON check GSON https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Versioning-Support. What you're saying seems right to me. 3) Even if slowier, for you own sake, it is still worth using RequestFactory :).

Comment: Thanks. GSON looks attractive, but raises some extra questions concerning versioning. But I think the initial question is solved. The new question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447117/json-data-storage-with-versioning . Would be nice if you could help me their as well :)